# How to use svn commands in Cygwin

Tags: svn, cygwin

How can I use `svn export`, `svn checkout` etc commands in Cygwin?

Do I need to install any other feature? I am using version 2.738.

For example, I'd like to be able to run

```
svn export http://svn/trunk/Test/code /TESTEXPORT
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you do. Check the packagelist in the cygwin setup.exe, and pick all the *svn*-like packages then install them. For typical usage such as update, commit, show history it's almost perfect.

**UPDATE**
*(not to steal credit but apparently an important addition)*

The package "subversion" should be installed as well.

Comment: Thanks i have updated my packages now svn commands are working.

Comment: You can also use the Tortoise SVN installed svn client from within Cygwin. Remember to adjust the paths for non-unix requirements though.

Comment: Search for 'subversion' in setup.exe.  (Found by searching http://cygwin.com/packages for 'svn'.)

Comment: The "UPDATE" in the answer is the key thing. The svn command-line command is packaged under "subversion".